# i create a dockerfile in my github account i want to build my dockerfile in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: github, jenkins, build, dockerfile, pipeline

[need script for docker file build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dbw3.png)

I need build success output and run all my Docker file commands in console output

Comment: There is so much less information in your question.

     1. What type of job you have? IS it a pipeline?
     2. If Pipeline what type? Declarative or scripted? 
     3. What have you tried until now?


From only this much information I would say use pipeline from git scm in your job and use the github repo.